# Illegal string offset in array foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I send this array to php and when I want to show the results the following error appears:

"Illegal string offset 'nombre_color'"

This is the array result made with print_r() in the same php before the error:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [med_id] => 1
            [codigo] => 1111111111
            [medida] => XL
            [nombre_color] => Negro
            [color] => #000000
            [precio] => 1111
            [anterior] => 1000
            [stock] => 100
            [disponible] => 1
        )
)
```

And this is the part of code that gives me error:

```
foreach($medidas as $medida){
    $med_id = $medida['med_id'];
    $codigo = $medida['codigo'];
    $medida = $medida['medida'];
    $nombre_color = $medida['nombre_color'];
    $color = $medida['color'];
    $precio = $medida['precio'];
    $anterior = $medida['anterior'];
    $stock = $medida['stock'];
    $disponible = $medida['disponible'];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The name of foreach var ($medida) and index of one element was the same

Answer (score 0):

> [**array_shift()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) : *Shift an element off the beginning of array*
>
> **[extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)** : *Import variables into the current symbol table from an array*

You could use `array_shift` wit `extract`

```
$medidas = array_shift($medidas);
extract($medidas);//This will make each index as variable i.e.
echo $med_id;
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/bmVX6

Comment: Extract is lame - forget about IDE and static analysis.